# call back query send duplicate messages node-telegram-bot-api

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

Whenever inline button clicked by user call back query send duplicate messages so what type of changes I need to do to bot not send duplicate messages.

```
      var keyboard = [];
      movieRatingList.map((movie, idx) => {
        var movieRating = Math.round(movie.rating * 10) / 10;
        if (movieRating == bestRating) {
          var firstName = movieList[idx].firstName;
          keyboard.push([{ text: firstName, callback_data: idx }]);
        }
      });

      bot.sendMessage(userChatId, userText, {
        reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
          resize_keyboard: true,
          inline_keyboard: keyboard,
        }),
      });

      bot.on("callback_query", (callBackData) => {
        var idx = Number(callBackData.data);

        var fileID = movieList[idx].file_id;
        var firstName = movieList[idx].firstName;
        console.log(fileID);
        console.log(firstName);
        bot.sendDocument(userChatId, fileID, { caption: firstName });
        
      });
```